# Can I disable Touch ID on MBP?

Tags: high-sierra

I upgraded to High Sierra, asked for my password.  No problem.

It acts like it’s booting...the progress bar fills, then it says password is required to enable Touch ID... I cannot for the life of me get passed this.  It says it’s wrong everytime.  I have even reinstalled High Sierra and gotten the same message.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you enter your password? [Touch ID is always disabled immediately after restart](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/297388/37797)

Comment: It does the double shake like it’s incorrect. But when I reboot and it asks at startup it works.  This is a second prompt after it has booted

Comment: What happens if you start in Safe Mode (https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25617?locale=en_US) and/or you perform an SMC reset (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Active Directory issue. Simply taking Tim to the office and using their network was enough to fix the issue.